# Adding a summary row/column to a 2D table

Tags: list-manipulation, table

How can a summary row and a summary column be added to a 2D-table that can calculate `ChiSquareDistribution` values?

```
data = {{40, 60}, {10, 90}}
TableForm[data, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"case group", "control group"}, {"not good", 
    "good"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]
marginC = Total@data
marginR = Total[data, {2}]
expect = (List /@ marginR) . {marginC}/Total@Flatten@data
TableForm[expect, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"case group", 
    "control group"}, {"not good expect", "good expect"}}, 
 TableAlignments -> Center]
k = Total@Flatten@ (((data - expect)^2)/expect)
CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[2 - 1], 1. k]
```

The summary value of rows and columns must be calculated automatically as shown in the picture below. The initial data data only needs to input a two-dimensional array. The `TableHeadings` also need to be updated.

[image]

Comment: **horizontal column** what is a horizontal column? Do you mean a row? I never seen this term horizontal column before, that is what I am asking.

Comment: @Nasser That's what you mean

Comment: Rows and columns，The summary value of rows and columns can be calculated automatically. For example, the sum of my handwritten rows and columns in the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expect0 = Append[#, Total[#]] & /@ expect;
expect0 = Append[expect0, Total[#] & /@ Transpose[expect0]];
TableForm[expect0, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"case group", "control group", 
    "Total"}, {"not good expect", "good expect", "Total"}}, 
 TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: This summary operation is required for both tables

Comment: How does the first table summarize rows and columns?

Comment: I think with my example you should be able to do the second table yourself.

Answer (score 7):

**Using `ArrayReduce`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

data = {{40, 60}, {10, 90}}
expect = {{25, 75}, {25, 75}}
oheadings = {{"case group", "control group"}, {"not good", "good"}};

summaryTable[otable_, oheadings_, f_] := Module[{v1, v2},
  v1 = Transpose@Join[Transpose@otable, {ArrayReduce[f, otable, 2]}];
  v2 = Join[v1, {ArrayReduce[f, v1, 1]}, 1];
  TableForm[v2, TableHeadings -> (Append[#, ToString@f] & /@ oheadings)
   , TableAlignments -> Center]
  ]
```

**Usage:**

e.g.; Calculating the `Total` for the first table and the `Mean` for the second table, both on a row- as well as column-wise basis:

```
summaryTable[data, oheadings, Total]
summaryTable[expect, oheadings, Mean]
```

[image]